# Ubuntu 18.04 Apache Reverse proxy with SSL to Node

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-18.04, digital-ocean

I have a react app with routing and served in apache server. The backend of the app is nodejs. They are both hosted one droplet on DigitalOcean.

When I visited my site e.g. https://example.com it displayed the app but it can't get the api in  nodejs backend because its not https (http://server_ip:8080). Searching on the net I found the Apache Reverse Proxy. Here is my virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/example.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and when i test https://example.com/api/user/all/ it returned:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 443</address>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: https traffic is on port 443, not 80.
Can you change the virtualhost to listen on port 443?

Comment: I changed it to port 443, restart apache2 and still I get the same error.. but if i change the request url to http://server_ip it works and returned data. By the way I'm using postman to test it

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing too much details. I believe you want your  ReactJS app to run on `example.com` and your NodeJS api to run on `example.com/api`. It might be easier to create a subdomain for your api so you can forward all that traffic to a specific port `api.example.com`